# Prompt for confirmation when navigating away from stack snippet

Tags: feature-request, editor, stack-snippets

In the following specific case:

1. Click 'Ask Question'
2. Click the stack snippet button *without* entering any other text or question titles or anything in the editor first.

When you navigate away from the page (back button, reload, etc.), you currently are *not* prompted for confirmation with the "unsaved changes" dialog.

This is a request to trigger the unsaved changes confirmation in this case (in addition to the current behavior where it is displayed when you enter text in the editor).

Authoring a code snippet, even if nothing else is entered yet, *does* represent unsaved work.

Current workaround if you don't want to get bitten by this (for example if your stupid laptop's stupid keyboard has stupid browser back/forward keys [*right next to the stupid arrows because*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZh9J.png) ***really? why? how does that make ANY sense???*** ... ahem) is to always enter something, even if it's just temporary gibberish, into the editor before clicking the code snippet button.